# How to read JMeter test as a readable text response?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

How to read JMeter test as a readable text response?

Recorded scripts:

[image]

[image]

View result tree

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**OSCP** stands for [Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol), so you need to decode it via [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Bouncy Castle libraries](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

For instance add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request and add the relevant script to decode the response and check its status.

See [How to Load Test OCSP with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ocsp-jmeter) article for more details including example code snippets.

Comment: Hi Dimitri Can you check my JSR223 PostProcessor Script to decode the response is correct for this example (see my answer)?

Comment: any answers ? dimitri?

Answer (score 0):

Bellow error given with JSR223PostProcessor,

[image]